# Quick edit and user see Edit in Grid View

Tags: sharepoint-online

I created a custom list with a custom view that shows only my documents.  I put the list on a page.  When a full control user is on the page they see EDIT IN GRID VIEW instead of what I see: QUICK EDIT.  What would cause this?  Also when they click their edit in grid view it throws this error:

Something went wrong

Loading chunk 14 failed. (missing: https://spoprod-a.akamaihd.net/files/sp-client/chunk.addon-sp-itemsetquickeditlist_en-us_cb1f2686061679264013.js)

Comment: I used to see "Quick Edit", but now I see "Edit in grid view". I think MS has updated SPO. Other users, not site collection administrator, are still seeing "Quick Edit". However, haven't heard anyone having any issues. Are all your lists/libraries throwing error or just a particular one?

Answer (score 0):

It may be caused by targeted release in the SharePoint Online.

Go to Microsoft 365 admin center -> Settings -> Org Setting -> Under the Organization profile tab, choose Release preferences -> Set "Targeted release for everyone".

Reference:

[Set up the Standard or Targeted release options](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/admin/manage/release-options-in-office-365?view=o365-worldwide)